# SUM in case expression SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sum, case

I'm working on this query:

```
SELECT
       [D_INV_DATE_ID]
      ,[INVOICE_NO]
      ,[CUSTOMER_ID]
      ,[DOCUMENT_STATUS]
      ,[Total_Charge]
      ,[OPEN_CHARGE]
      ,[DSS_UPDATE_TIME]
      ,Case 
         when Total_Charge < 20 then 'less than 20'
         when Total_Charge > 20 and Total_Charge <= 50 then '20-50'
         when Total_Charge > 50 and Total_Charge <= 100 then '50-100'
         when Total_Charge > 100 then '100+'
      End as SortedBySum
  FROM [TEST].[angel].[inv3]
```

I need to SUM all the when statements just how they are right now by groups, so the first one has to be all the sums below 20 to be summed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I guess correct, I think this following logic will help-

```
SELECT 
[D_INV_DATE_ID],[INVOICE_NO],[CUSTOMER_ID],[DOCUMENT_STATUS],[Total_Charge],
[OPEN_CHARGE],[DSS_UPDATE_TIME],
SUM(CASE WHEN Total_Charge <= 20 THEN Total_Charge ELSE 0 END) [sum_below_equal_20],
SUM(CASE WHEN Total_Charge > 20 and Total_Charge <= 50 THEN Total_Charge ELSE 0 END) [sum_above_20_below_50],
SUM(CASE WHEN Total_Charge > 50 and Total_Charge <= 100 THEN Total_Charge ELSE 0 END) [sum_above_50_below_100],
SUM(CASE WHEN Total_Charge > 100 THEN Total_Charge ELSE 0 END) [sum_100_above]
FROM [TEST].[angel].[inv3]
GROUP BY
[D_INV_DATE_ID],[INVOICE_NO],[CUSTOMER_ID],[DOCUMENT_STATUS],[Total_Charge],
[OPEN_CHARGE],[DSS_UPDATE_TIME]
```

Comment: Please check now @RinganarR

Comment: It's working now but the result isn't quite the one I need, so im gonna try to explain it so you can maybe figure it out because im stuck atm, basically we need to sum all the values that go into each case, atm it sums values but for every line and we need to sum all the data that will go into <= 20 for example and give out 1 summed up number.

Comment: Can you add some sample data with your expected output from them?

Comment: Okay, for instance we have the following values in <=20 - Total_Charge has 20 for ID 1, 10 for ID 2 and 14 for ID 3, in the end we need it to show the summed up value of them so that would be 20+10+14=44 end result.

Comment: Without the listed items in select and group by it gives out the right result, because with them its still per ID not the total sum.

Comment: Please add some sample data with table structure. Other wise it is difficult to understand the issue.